# How to handle input from child to parent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios

I'm trying to handle an input change from child to parent in React, and for some reason I can't type more than one letter, i left the code here:

Parent:

```
import querystring from 'querystring'
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import axios from 'axios'
import cookie from 'react-cookies'

import Admin from './Admin'
import Tienda from './Tienda/Tienda'
import LoginAdmin from './LoginAdmin/LoginAdmin'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

export default class Root extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      redirect: false,
      mail: '',
      pass: '',
    }
    this.login = this.login.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    this.setState({ mail: e.target.value })
  }

  login() {
    const data = querystring.stringify({grant_type: 'password', client_id: 2, client_secret: 'HKpmjbWwRgt7McmpqZC2Dfp5JuFFRjEvj8U0G6aE', username: 'ralvaradosmx2013@gmail.com', password: 'ricardo1'})
    axios.post('http://localhost/ICEBIRD/back/public/oauth/token', data)
      .then((token) => {
        cookie.save('token', token.data.access_token, { path: '/' })
        this.setState({ redirect: true })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
  render() {
    const LoginAdminProps = (props) => {
      return (
        <LoginAdmin
          login={this.login.bind(this)}
          redirect={this.state.redirect}
          handleTextChange={this.handleChange}
          email={this.state.mail}
          pass={this.state.pass}
          {...props}
        />
      )
    }
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Tienda} />
          <Route exact path="/admin" component={LoginAdminProps} />
          <Route path="/admin/dashboard" component={Admin} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Child:

```
import React from 'react'

import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

import './LoginAdmin.css'

export default class LoginAdmin extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.redirect) {
      return(
        <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/admin/dashboard',
        }}/>
      )
    }

    return(
      <div className='background'>
        <div className="login-box">
          <div className="login-logo">
            <b>Admin</b>IceBird
          </div>
          <div className="login-box-body">
            <p className="login-box-msg">Inicia sesión para entrar al panel de administración</p>
            <div className="form-group has-feedback">
              <input id="mail" className="form-control" onChange={this.props.handleTextChange} placeholder="Email" type="email"/>
              <span className="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group has-feedback">
              <input id="pass" className="form-control" onChange={this.props.handleTextChange} placeholder="Contraseña" type="password"/>
              <span className="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block btn-sm" onClick={this.props.login}>Enviar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It seems the problem is when, in Parent, I use set setState, then it dosen't let me write more than one character if I remove it I can actually see the console.log working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to keep the *handleTextChange* method in the child itself & update parent state on click of the button?

Here's a sample implementation:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qidphg?file=LoginAdmin.js

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass value in your .

exemple:

child:

```
<input
    id="mail"
    className="form-control"
    onChange={this.props.handleTextChange}
    placeholder="Email"
    type="email"
    value={this.props.email}/>
```

and:

```
<input
    id="pass"
    className="form-control"
    onChange={this.props.handleTextChange}
    placeholder="Contraseña" type="password"
    value={this.props.pass}/>
```

Comment: Thanks to both, it was indeed the value but now everytime I change the input I lose focus. So I can't write a whole word, just characters

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you type something props.handleTextChange is being called which updates the state of parent component which re renders child with initail values of input field as none.
You have to set value of input field to this.props.email or this.props.pass
accordingly.

```html
<input id="mail" className="form-control" onChange={this.props.handleTextChange} value={this.props.email} placeholder="Email" type="email"/>
```